Zero as sum of four squares in a field
I have the following question in regards to non-commutative algebra: 

Let $F$ be a field s.t. $char(F) \neq 2$. If $0$ can be presented as the sum of four squares of elements in $F$, not all zero, then it can be presented as the sum of three squares in $F$, not all zero.

This question looks simple at first, but I couldn't solve it. In the case where at least one of the elements is zero, the claim is trivial. The difficult part is assuming that all elements are non-zero. 
At first, I thought of using generalized quaternion algebra, i.e., if $x^2+y^2+z^2+t^2=0$, then the quaternion algebra $(-1,-t^2)_F$ splits, and thus $x^2 + y^2 + z^2$ can be presented as the sum of two squares. However, it's isomorphic to $(-1,-1)_F$, which I believe does not split. 
I have a suspicion that this claim is false, or that its proof is non-trivial. Am I missing something here? 
Thank you all for your help!

Nothing complicated required, just algebraic manipulation. $\quad$ Hint: Given $a^2 + b^2 + ^2 + d^2 $ (not necessarily 0), then find some $e, f, g$ such that $e^2 + f^2 + g^2 = (a^2 + b^2 + c^2 +d^2)^2$ (hence is 0). $\quad$ You also have the further hint from the question that we need char $F \neq 2$, suggesting that some of these terms would be 0 in a field of characteristic 2 (This mainly comes in  the "not all zero" verification)

@CalvinLin Pretty hard even with the hint. How do we choose $e$?

@MartinBrandenburg  Oh wait, I didn't realize that this was non-commutative algebra. I take that back, the identity doesn't work as the cross terms do not cancel.

I think $F$ is commutative, following the usual definition of a field. The tag noncommutative algebra refers to the attempt using quaternions over $F$. @CalvinLin

In which case, to choose $e$, we'd likely want something like $ wa^2 + xb^2 + yc^2 +zd^2$ where $ w, x, y, z \in { -1, 0, 1}$, in order to get to the RHS. With a suitable choice, we can determine $f, g$. $\quad$ This is a well-known result called (highlight text) $\color{white}{\text{ Lebesgue Identity} }$, which is also a corollary of another well-known result (highlight text) $\color{white} {\text{Euler four-square identity}}$.

Why do you think that $(-1,-1)_F$ does not split if $x^2+y^2+z^2+w^2$ represents zero?

Generally speaking the minimal length of a zero sum of non-zero squares in a field of characteristic not $2$ is always of the form $2^k+1$, and $k$ is called the level of the field.

The assumption on the characteristic is not necessary. If $\mathrm{char}(F)=2$, then $0 = 1^2 + 1^2 + 0^2$ is an example.

Indeed, it's possible to prove this using standard results about generalized quaternion algebras. Consider the quaternion algebra $( -1,-1)_F$. If $a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2=0$ with at least one of $a,b,c,d$ non-zero, then $(a+bi+cj+dk)(a-bi-cj-dk)=0$, so $( -1,-1)_F$ contains zero divisors and hence cannot be a division algebra, i.e. it splits.
Now a general theorem about generalized quaternion algebras says that $(a,b)_F$ splits iff the diagonal quadratic form $\langle 1,-a,-b\rangle$ represents zero. This is proved in most discussions about generalized quaternion algebras, i.e. Gilles-Szamuely or these notes. For $a=-1,b=-1$, we get the quadratic form $x^2+y^2+z^2$.

\begin{equation}(a^2+b^2-c^2-d^2)^2+(-2ad+2bc)^2+(2ac+2bd)^2=(a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2)^2=0\end{equation}
You have that if $F$ has char$F=2$ then it can happen this formula is wrong, infact in $\mathbb{Z}_2$ you have $a=b=c=d=1$ and this formula is wrong. But if you have a field of Characteristic 2 and $a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2=0$ with $a\neq 0$, then $a^2+b^2+(c+d)^2=0$.

The formula $(a^2+b^2-c^2-d^2)^2+(-2ad+2bc)^2+(2ac+2bd)^2=(a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2)^2$ holds in every commutative ring. So I think you want to say something different. Also, we need to check that one of the squares is non-zero. Why is that?

Yeah the problem was not in the formula itself but in the fact that cannot be used in the cases where we have char=2. In other cases you can make some calculations, where you can put the three squares equal to zero. You would find that it cannot happen. Hint: Infact if you have $a^2+b^2=c^2+d^2$ and $ad=bc$ and $ac=-bd$ you can find that $a^2+b^2=c^2+d^2=0$. Then if you multiply both sides you have $a^2c^2+a^2d^2+b^2c^2+b^2d^2=0$. Can you see it...

The assumption on the characteristic is not necessary. If $\mathrm{char}(F)=2$, then $0 = 1^2 + 1^2 + 0^2$ is an example.
